# Curve fitting of sine function in python using scipy is not yielding desired output

Tags: scipy, python-3.7, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit sine function on my data. No errors are shown but it doesn't seem to work.

```
python
def sin_fun(x,a,b):
    return (a*np.sin(b*x))

p_opt,p_cov=cf(sin_fun,xdata,ydata)
print(p_opt)

plt.plot(xdata,sin_fun(xdata,*p_opt))
plt.scatter(xdata,ydata)
plt.show()
```

This is the output I am getting:

[image: this the output i'm getting]

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I have simulated your data. There are 2 problems with your code as to why it isn't doing what you want. First is that your `sin_fun` needs a y-offset parameter, otherwise the function will always be symmetrical about `y = 0`. Secondly, the fit works better if you can provide `curve_fit` with a reasonable guess. This is done using the `p0` argument. Have a look here:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit as cf
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# simulate your data
xdata = np.linspace(0, 25000, 256)
ydata = 15000 * np.sin(xdata/2000) + 22000

# add some noise
ydata += np.random.rand(xdata.size) * 2000

# sin function needs a y-offset -> c
def sin_fun(x,a,b,c):
    return a*np.sin(b*x)+c

# need a reasonable guess -> note that the guess is not quite right but curve_fit still works
p_opt,p_cov=cf(sin_fun,xdata,ydata, p0=(10000, 1/2500, 15000))
print(p_opt)

plt.plot(xdata,sin_fun(xdata,*p_opt))
plt.plot(xdata,ydata, 'r.', ms=1)
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

With these fixes you can get a good fit. You could also add a phase parameter to your function to help fit other sinusoids.